# Swapping CTRL-CAPS on Windows 10

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10, emacs, keyboard-layout

I've been able to remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Caps</kbd> on previous versions of Windows (XP and 7) by using [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq-w32/Swap-Caps-NT.html#Swap-Caps-NT) tutorial. Perhaps the [scancodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj128267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Scan%20code%20mapper%20for%20keyboards]) are different for Windows 10. I'm not sure. Whatever the reason, this method no longer works.

So does anyone know how to remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Caps</kbd> on Windows 10?

Comment: The scancodes are not different.

Comment: But why is there a tag on `emacs`?

Comment: @Prasanna strong relevance to emacs users.

Answer (score 2):

Should work. I've done various remaps using a Powershell script (needs to be run from Admin PowerShell Console). Remap pairs can be added or subtracted easily. It's set up for the remap you desire, just copy & paste.

```
##############################################################
$SimplePairs = @(
0x3a, 0x1d # CapsLock > L Ctrl
0x1d, 0x3a # L Ctrl > CapsLock
)
$ExtendedPairs = @(
# 0x5d, 0xe0, 0x1d, 0xe0 # ContextMenu > R Ctrl
)
$ByteCount = 2 * $SimplePairs.Length + $ExtendedPairs.Length + 16
$Remap = New-Object -TypeName byte[] -ArgumentList $ByteCount
$Remap[8] = $SimplePairs.Length/2 + $ExtendedPairs.Length/4 + 1
For ($i = 0 ; $i -lt $SimplePairs.Length ; $i += 2) {
   $Remap[$i * 2 + 12] = $SimplePairs[$i]
   $Remap[$i * 2 + 14] = $SimplePairs[$i + 1]
}
For ($i = 0 ; $i -lt $ExtendedPairs.Length ; $i += 4) {
   $Offset = $SimplePairs.Length * 2
   $Remap[$i + 12 + $Offset] = $ExtendedPairs[$i]
   $Remap[$i + 13 + $Offset] = $ExtendedPairs[$i + 1]
   $Remap[$i + 14 + $Offset] = $ExtendedPairs[$i + 2]
   $Remap[$i + 15 + $Offset] = $ExtendedPairs[$i + 3]
}
$args = @{
Path  = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout'
Name  = 'ScanCode Map'
Value = $Remap
Force = $True
}
New-ItemProperty @args
```

Keith

Answer (score 1):

If you want to swap CTRL and CAPS, this [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script works for me on Windows 10 (swapping left control and caps; change `LCtrl` to `Ctrl` to make both control keys be caps lock):

```
LCtrl::Capslock
Capslock::LCtrl
```

If you want to add a keyboard shortcut for pressing control and then caps lock, you may be running into problems with your keyboard hardware; have you tried it with a different physical keyboard, or a simulated one?

Comment: great if you open .ahk automatically at login

Answer (score 0):

[Keyboard Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager) that comes with [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys) has this feature.

Once you install & run it, it allows you to choose a physical key (by clicking "type" and actually pressing down the key), and a corresponding mapped key.

See screenshot below for setting <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> → <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

[image]